# is there a way to stop printing on Putty terminal?

Tags: putty

I am collecting logs from remote device over seial port using Putty. Logs are coming from device automatically and getting printed on putty terminal. I want to store all the logs from remote device in a log file, without getting printed on putty terminal. Please suggest how to do the same. Reading manual and google search did n't help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to enable logging in PuTTY. Set *Session logging* to *All session output* on *Logging* tab under *Session* tab  (you can also set the filename below). This will not, howerver, disable output in PuTTY.

Alternatively you could just get the data from the device without using PuTTY, typing the following in `cmd.exe` window:

```
type com1: > logfile.txt
```

Where `com1:` is the port which your device is connected to. Change `>` to `>>` if the `logfile.txt` should not be overwritten each time you start the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to redirect stderr and stdout into a file. 
`some_command 2>&1 > stdout.txt`
Everything will be written to `stdout.txt`